# AudioInputStream from file conversion gives "frameLength=-1"

Tags: java, audio, audioformat, audioinputstream

I am trying to obtain an AudioInputStream from a file in a specific format. When I open the file in `fileStream` I get a positive frameLength meaning the file can be read and the AudioInputStream effectively has data. Now I want to convert it with AudioSystem with `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(format, fileStream);` and the obtained stream `audioStream` has a frameLength of -1. I even made sure the conversion is supported and it sure is.

```
public void openFile() throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException {
    AudioInputStream fileStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFile);
    AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 8, 1, true, true);
    boolean supported = AudioSystem.isConversionSupported(format, fileStream.getFormat());
    if(supported) {
        audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(format, fileStream);
        System.out.println("Opened file: " + audioFile.getName());
    }else{
        System.out.println("Couldn't open file: " + audioFile.getName());
        throw new IOException();
    }
}
```

I am completely stuck and I haven't found anyone with the same exact problem. I welcome any suggestions of different libraries but I would prefer to keep using this one as I'm used to it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay figured it out, I'm dumb.

A frameLength of -1 is, according to the AudioSystem constants, `NOT_SPECIFIED` which means that, when converting audio, you lose that information.

I was thinking that was the problem because of another unrelated problem.